# AlarmManager sets repetition but BroadcastReceiver doesn't receive alarm

Tags: java, android

I faced kind of issue during making some **appwidget**. I wanted to use AlarmManager to **refresh** my widget **every 15 minutes**. Unfortunately my implementation of **BroadcastReceiver doesn't receive anything** so Toast message doesn't show.

I went thought many similar issues and solutions delivered here and in Google. Everything what I wrote seems to fit exactly according to tutorials, people answers, and other docs. I must have made little bug or I misunderstood something, but I really can't see what is wrong here.

Would you please be so kind to look in the code I pasted below?

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="pl.test.mywidget"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".view.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".view.LmWidgetProvider" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider" android:resource="@xml/widget_info" />
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name=".service.WidgetUpdateService"/>

        <receiver android:name=".service.DeviceBootReceiver"
                  android:enabled="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

MyWidgetProvider.java

```
@Override
public void onDisabled(Context context) {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(context, WidgetUpdateService.class);
    final PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);
    final AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm.cancel(pending);
    super.onDisabled(context);
}

@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context) {
    super.onEnabled(context);
    final Intent intent = new Intent(context, WidgetUpdateService.class);
    final PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);
    final AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    int widgetRefreshInterval = 1000 * 60 * 1;  //1 minute just for tests
    alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+1000, widgetRefreshInterval, pending);
    //alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()+1000, widgetRefreshInterval, pending);
}
```

WidgetUpdateService.java

```
public class WidgetUpdateService extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "WidgetUpdateService", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Comment: your pending Intent Should be like.. PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Comment: I knew it should be a little boggart hidden somewhere... I'm blind after couple of hours of looking at it. You're right. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change Your Pending Intent to.

```
PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

**PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT :** Flag indicating that if the described PendingIntent already exists, then keep it but replace its extra data with what is in this new Intent.

**getBroadcast :**
Retrieve a PendingIntent that will perform a broadcast, like calling Context.sendBroadcast().

**getService :**
Retrieve a PendingIntent that will start a service, like calling Context.startService().